# Pre-dual of $W^{1,\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

While reading about direct methods in the Calculus of variations, I came across the weak $*$ convergence in the space $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set. What does this mean?

I think that the key is finding the predual of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, and I bet it is $W^{1,1}$. However I'm stuck in proving this, here are the steps I'm following.

$W^{1,\infty}$ and $W^{1,1}$ naturally embed into $(L^\infty )^{n+1}$ and $(L^1)^{n+1}$ respectively, by the mapping $u \mapsto (u ,\nabla u)$. So I must show that the image of $W^{1,\infty}\subseteq (L^\infty )^{n+1}$ is the dual of  $W^{1,1}\subseteq(L^1)^{n+1}$. Therefore, let $x^*$ be a functional on $W^{1,1}\subseteq(L^1)^{n+1}$. This can be extended to a functional on all of $(L^1)^{n+1}$, and since the dual of $((L^1)^n)^*=(L^\infty)^n$ in a canonical way, we can say that $x^*(v, \nabla v)=(u,v)+\sum_{i=1}^n(u_i,\partial_i v)$, for some $(u,u_1,...,u_n) \in (L^\infty )^{n+1}$ [here $(u,v)=\int_\Omega uvdx$].

So, it would be nice if $u_i=\partial_i u$. How do I show this?

Comment: I think you want $W^{-1,1}$ instead.

Comment: @user10354138 I don't know this space, can you provide a reference?

Comment: Recall $W^{-k,p}(\Omega)$ is defined as the dual space of $W^{k,p'}_0(\Omega)$ where $p'=p/(p-1)$ is the Holder conjugate.

Comment: Okay, thanks! @user10354138 So I should try to prove that the pre-dual of $W^{1, \infty}$ is the dual of $W^{1,1}_0$?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. However, the pre-dual of $W^{1,\infty}$ cannot be $W_0^{1,1}$ since the pre-dual has to be larger than $L^1$.